# How to upload a Hugo website into pages.sr.ht?

Tags: curl, hugo, blogdown

I am working on uploading my Hugo website (using blogdown) onto sourcehut pages following the instruction : [instructions](https://srht.site/quickstart) but I can't manage to upload the tarball to pages.sr.ht/publish. The curl instruction `curl --oauth2-bearer "access token"-Fcontent=@site.tar.gz https://pages.sr.ht/publish/username.srht.site`  always end up with an error `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

PS : I do use my own 'username' and access token

If i follow the [automating deployments instructions](https://srht.site/automating-deployments) I still can't manage to upload the tarball but the error is different : `curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400`. You can find the complete log [here](https://builds.sr.ht/%7Emallorydazza/job/663290)

Is there something I do wrong ? How can I upload the tarball successfully ?

Comment: Could you please like to the build log for us to help investigating?  You could also try to reach the maintainers via the mailing list or IRC.

Comment: I have edited the question. You to find the logs [here](https://builds.sr.ht/~mallorydazza/job/663290)

Comment: I would guess that it timed out on pages.sr.ht side unpacking and uploading the individual files, i.e. not your fault.  Please contact the maintainers.